# Using output of one lua function as input of another function in tex file

Tags: luatex, strings, lua, luacode, directlua

The following is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
function string(x)
tex.sprint(x)
end
function combine(x,y)
tex.sprint(x.." "..y)
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\directlua{string(#1)}}
\newcommand{\othertest}[2]{\directlua{combine(#1,#2)}}
\test{"abc"}\\
\othertest{"abc"}{"def"}
\end{document}
```

This works fine.  The following code also works well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
function string(x)
tex.sprint(x)
end
function combine(x,y)
tex.sprint(x.." "..y)
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\directlua{string(#1)}}
\newcommand{\othertest}[2]{\directlua{combine(#1,#2)}}
\test{"abc"}\\
\othertest{"abc"}{"def"}\\
\def\str{"abc"}
\def\otherstr{"def"}
\othertest{\str}{\otherstr}
\end{document}
```

The following is another code which doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
function string(x)
tex.sprint(x)
end
function combine(x,y)
tex.sprint(x.." "..y)
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\directlua{string(#1)}}
\newcommand{\othertest}[2]{\directlua{combine(#1,#2)}}
\test{"abc"}\\
\othertest{"abc"}{"def"}\\
\def\str\test{"abc"}
\def\otherstr\test{"def"}
\othertest{\str}{\otherstr}
\end{document}
```

I am working with some complex document where I want to use output of one lua function as input of another function in tex file itself. I know I can do this in lua itself. But I am working with something general. Say I have defined addition and subtraction functions for two numbers in lualatex. Now I want to use output of one function to the other. For example

```
 \def\x{2}
    \def\y{3}
    \add{x}{y}
\subtract{x}{y}
```

This will work. However if I want to do

```
\subtract{\add{x}{y}}{y}
```

Here is what I mean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
function add(x,y)
return tex.print(x+y)
end
function subtract(x,y)
return tex.print(x-y)
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\add}[2]{\directlua{add(#1,#2)}}
\newcommand{\subtract}[2]{\directlua{subtract(#1,#2)}}
\add{3}{2}\\
\subtract{3}{2}
\subtract{{\add{3}{2}}{1}}
\end{document}
```

This won't work. I know I can define another function in lualatex which will do both addition and subtraction. But as I mentioned, I want to do this in tex itself. How can new commands be defined in tex or latex to solve this?

Comment: `\def\str\test{"abc"}` defines `\str` to be a token that must always be followed by `\test` or gives an error, and if it is followed by test it returns `abc` , I would guess that isn't the intended definition? similarly `\othertest{\str}` is an error as you have defined it to require a `\test` token as the next token.

Comment: you say `\subtract{\add{x}{y}}{y}` will not work but you give no example definition (I would expect that to work)

Comment: Moreover, your definition of `string(x)` and `combine(x,y)` contain `tex.sprint` statements, which are instructions to print to the output document. If you want to collect the values for further processing instead of printing them directly, then you need `return` statements in your functions.

Comment: @Marijn  the arguments are fully expanded before being passed to lua so it isn't really code just a list of character tokens, only thing really missing is that (if you want Lua to see it as a string) it needs `"` adding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think the OP intended the arguments to be passed to Lua verbatim as a string, I think it was expected that the command was executed and the return value used as argument to the function. But I didn't realize that the arguments are fully expanded, so I'll remove my first comment.

Comment: @Marijn that is essentially what happens: the two `\directlua` in the argument are fully expanded so causing the lua expressions to be invoked before the resulting tokens are passed to the outer lua call

Comment: @Marijn no explicit Lua return statement is needed here as the result is collected and passed back to Lua via tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle regarding the expansion (your 15:34 comment) I'm not sure I understand, the arguments are expanded only during the `tex.sprint(x.." "..y)` call, not before/during the arguments are passed to the `combine` call.

Comment: @Marijn no, in the (working) version in my answer the two calls to `\test` in `\othertest{"\test{"abc"}"}{"\test{"def"}"}` are expanded before the `combine` starts  that means both calls to the Lua function `string` are fully evaluated before the chunk containing the `combine` call is started.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if you put `tex.sprint("XYZ")` as a first statement in `combine` then this seems to be executed before the `string` calls.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have edited the question with \add and \subtract.

Comment: @Marijn what is passed to Lua has t be a valid Lua string, so it clearly can not have `\directlua` etc in it, they are all expanded first (however the print statements from nested calls get buffered. See the add/subtract version I just added to my answer

Comment: @user61681 I'd already added an add/subtract version to the answer, your error in the version added is again a simple tex error unrelated to Lua, you have defined `\subtract` to take two arguments but only supplied one, so it takes `\end`  from `\end{document}` as the second argument and goes wrong... `! Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition.
\@checkend `...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I got it. Thanks for all your efforts. This trick however doesn't solve my issue. It is about matrices which I will post in another question.

Comment: your last line should be `\subtract{\add{3}{2}}{1}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have posted new question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501440/nesting-of-functions-not-working-in-lualatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are not exactly clear but I think you want this, which runs without error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
function string(x)
tex.sprint(x)
end
function combine(x,y)
tex.sprint(x.." "..y)
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\directlua{string(#1)}}
\newcommand{\othertest}[2]{\directlua{combine(#1,#2)}}
\test{"abc"}\\
\othertest{"abc"}{"def"}\\
\othertest{"\test{"abc"}"}{"\test{"def"}"}
\end{document}
```

It is simpler to use if you add the `"` in the macro definitions not on every call:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
function string(x)
tex.sprint(x)
end
function combine(x,y)
tex.sprint(x.." "..y)
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\directlua{string("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}
\newcommand{\othertest}[2]{\directlua{combine("\luaescapestring{#1}","\luaescapestring{#2}")}}
\test{abc}\\
\othertest{abc}{def}\\
\othertest{\test{abc}}{\test{def}}
\end{document}
```

And this prints 7 from nested add and subtract

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\add}[2]{\directlua{tex.sprint(#1 + #2)}}
\newcommand{\subtract}[2]{\directlua{tex.sprint(#1 - #2)}}



% (2+(4-1))+2
\add{\add{2}{\subtract{4}{1}}}{2}

\end{document}
```