# Issue with xparse and lualatex

Tags: luatex, xparse, luacode, directlua

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,xparse,amsmath}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
local matrix = require "matrix"
local complex = require "complex"

function add(m,n)
  m=change(m)
  n=change(n)
  return tex.sprint(matrix.display(matrix.add(m,n)))
end

function change(m1)
  if type(m1) ~="string" then return  m1 end
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"\\","},{" )
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"\begin%{matrix%}","{{" ) 
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"begin%{matrix%}","{" )
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"%&","," )
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"end%{matrix%}","}}" )
  m1 = string.gsub(m1 , "%s+", "")
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,",{}","" )
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"},{{","{{" )
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"%(","{")
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"%)","}")
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"%[","{")
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,"%]","}")
  m1 = string.gsub(m1,";",",")
  if string.find(m1,"i") ~= nil then
     m1=loadstring("return "..m1)()
     m1 = matrix(m1):replace(complex)
     return m1
  else
     m1=loadstring("return "..m1)()
     return m1
  end
end

function matrix.display( mtx, format, dig )
  mtx = change(mtx)
  local format = format or "matrix"
  local dig = dig or 4
  local str = "\\begin{"..format.."}"

  for i = 1,#mtx do
      str = str.."\t"..complex.round(complex(mtx[i][1]),dig)
      for j = 2,#mtx[1] do
            str = str.." & "..complex.round(complex(mtx[i][j]),dig)
      end
      -- close line
      if i == #mtx then
         str = str
      else
         str = str .. " \\\\"
      end
  end
  return str .. "\\end{"..format.."} "
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}
\NewDocumentCommand{\matrixadd}{m m}{\directlua{add('#1','#2')}}
\def\n{{{2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,20}}}

\begin{document}

\[\matrixadd{\n}{\n}\]
%\[\matrixadd{\matrixadd{\n}{\n}}{\n}\]

\end{document}
```

Here I am using `matrix.lua` and `complex.lua` from the following links.

https://github.com/davidm/lua-matrix/blob/master/lua/matrix.lua

https://github.com/davidm/lua-matrix/blob/master/lua/complex.lua

These files are to be put in the same folder as that of tex file. The code is to be compiled with lualatex.

This code works fine. However when I uncomment the last line, it gives error. So there is trouble with nesting of commands. It gives the error `invalid escape sequence near '\m'`. So `\matrixadd` command works well when called alone. However it gives the error when nested. There are few possibilities. The error may be with my lua code. The error may be with lualatex or with xparse. Could someone point out the issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your lua function `add()` does `return tex.sprint(...)`. This is not useful, because `tex.sprint()` returns `nil`! Contrary to lua functions, (La)TeX macros don't have the concept of *return value*. A macro expands to some tokens, can gobble tokens, define macros, assign registers or TeX internal parameters, but it can't return a value as in lua. Expansion is close because it can be recursive, but expansion-only contexts present severe limitations to what can be done. You have to couple expansion with execution to do many things (increment loop counter, set flag...).

Comment: All this to say that your inner `\matrixadd` doesn't *return* a matrix that the outer `\matrixadd` can see. It would probably be easier to chain calls like this if they were all in lua space.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `if string.find(m1,"i") ~= nil then`, choose the simpler `if string.find(m1,"i") then`

Comment: @frougon Please have a look at this.  Nesting functions work.    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501440/nesting-of-functions-not-working-in-lualatex?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @user61681 I've seen it and it is clever (don't know why David removed his comment), but 1) it is not the way you are trying to add the matrices 2) it works by leaving TeX tokens in a suitable format in the input stream. This approaches but is not exactly a return value as in most other programming languages (this is: leaving carefully-chosen tokens in the input stream). I explained why your stuff doesn't work—no more, no less.

Comment: @frougon actually that's not true in luatex, `\directlua` is expandable so you can do arbitrary lua execution, which includes if you want, setting an arbitrary number of tex counter assignments, in a single expansion step.  It's a whole new world.... :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Whoooaaaaaa!! Incredible. Thanks for the info! Why did you remove your comment?

Comment: @frougon because it was wrong. This question is (I guess) not a duplicate of that but an attempt to address the comments under my answer where I pointed out that if you want to nest then the input and output syntax have to match. There I used lua table syntax, here the OP is attempting to pass strings withlatex tablular syntax and then parse on the fly to a Lua table (which could be made to work but seems vastly inefficient.)

Comment: I have checked the code in lua itself and it works as expected. I nested two add functions to get required output. When I don't use xparse and simply define newcomnad, it gives different error "command has an extra.. }". This error is thrown only when nesting otherwise not. So this might be an issue with lua and tex mingling.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of pretty-printing the Lua code chunk. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The only difference in your approach and my approach is that  you are ensuring correct `output` of add function and I am ensuring correct `input` of add function. Why would be this inefficient approach then?

Comment: for matrices of this size probably makes any difference, but in one case you are directly parsing a Lua input syntax by Lua's parser and in the other case you are passing in a string and applying multiple string pattern replacements before finally parsing the transformed string, but in practice a dozen or so gsub probably isn't any time at all so the efficiency or otherwise is probably not an issue.

Comment: agreed with your view.