# image positions up & down pattern on a scale from 0 to 1

Tags: floats, layout

I want to make the image arrangements as shown in the attachments. But I have no clue how to make such image arrangements. Please provide a solution to this problem.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(10,0);
\foreach \i in {1,3,...,9}
    \draw (\i,0) node[below]{0.\i} --++(90:2mm) node[above] {\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{example-image-a}};
\foreach \i in {2,4,...,8}
    \draw (\i,0) node[below]{0.\i} --++(90:2mm) +(0,1mm) [<-]--++(90:1.2cm) node[above] {\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{example-image-a}};
\draw (10,0) node[below]{1.0} --++(90:2mm) +(0,1mm) [<-]--++(90:1.2cm) node[above] {\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{example-image-a}};
\draw (0,0) node[below]{0.0}--++(90:2mm);   

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it using TeX's `\ifodd` test and `\pgfmathprintnumber` to print the graduations along the horizontal axis:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\newcommand*{\myImgWidth}{1.3cm}% to avoid repeating a hardcoded value

\newlength{\myImgHeight}
\settoheight{\myImgHeight}{\includegraphics[width=\myImgWidth]{example-image-a}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=10cm]
  \foreach \X in {0, 1, ..., 10} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\XF}{0.1*\X} % \XF is a float

    \node[below] at (\XF,0) {%
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, precision=1, fixed zerofill}
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\XF}};
    \draw (\XF,0) -- (\XF,0.2); % the tick mark

    \ifodd\X\relax
      \node[above] at (\XF,0.2)
        {\includegraphics[width=\myImgWidth]{example-image-a}};
    \else
      \draw[->]
        % You may want to replace \myImgHeight with your max. image height
        ($(\XF,0.4) + (0,\myImgHeight)$)
        node[above] {\includegraphics[width=\myImgWidth]{example-image-b}}
        -- (\XF,0.25);
    \fi
  }

  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

## Explanation of the \relax

The `\relax` following `\ifodd\X` is good practice here, because after `\ifodd`, TeX expands tokens until it has gathered a 〈number〉. In our case, it will *not* stop after expanding `\X`. Indeed, `\X` is not a  `\countdef` token in the example (alias for a `\count` register—*that* would be a 〈number〉), it is a *macro* that expands to one or two decimal digits. According to the TeX grammar for 〈number〉, after these digits, TeX will continue expanding tokens until it finds an unexpandable token that is not a decimal digit (by grammar rule, if the first such token is a space token, it is swallowed). So, without the `\relax` (which is an unexpandable token), it would try to expand `\node`, which might cause trouble, depending on what the expansion yields. With `\relax`, we are sure that the 〈number〉 following `\ifodd` is given by the expansion of `\X` and *nothing else*. You can read [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502271/73317) for more details on this subject.

Comment: thankyou so much...it works amazingly.

Comment: Glad you liked it. I improved the answer a little bit. :-)

Comment: @user187972 Your unaccept will teach me to spend time for you.